# onclick event onjavascript img tag not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to call a function on onclick event from img tag. But it appears it's not calling the function at all.

```
  <div class="portlet-title" style="background-color: #2E3638;">
        <h4><i class="icon-reorder"></i>Image List</h4>
        <%-- <asp:ImageButton id="imagelist" ImageUrl="~/Admin1/images/refresh-6.png" 
        style="height:30px; width:30px; margin-left:10px; cursor:pointer;" runat="server"          
        OnClick="imagelist_Click" Height="26px" />  --%>

       <img src="images/refresh-6.png" style="height:30px; width:30px; margin-left:10px; cursor:pointer;" onClick="Load();" />
  </div>
```

javascript code:

```
    function Load() {
            window.location("NewDesign.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Whats the error you getting ?

Comment: Where is that javascript code located?

Answer (score 1):

Use this Instead..

```
function Load() { 

            window.location.href = "NewDesign.aspx";
    }
```

http://jsbin.com/agiHAgI/1/

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that you should change this

```
function Load() 
{
      window.location = "NewDesign.aspx";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the URL try any of these method

```
document.location = "NewDesign.aspx";
```

or

```
window.location = "NewDesign.aspx";
```

Answer (score -1):

Onclick event for ImageButton of asp.net control is used for server side call.
You must use OnClientClick event of imageButton

```
OnClientClick="Load();"
```

Comment: OnClientClick is not a valid attribute of img tag

Comment: ohh. you are using img control instead asp.net Image.
Did you check by putting debugger in your javascript method that method is called or not ?

Comment: It's working with <asp.Image> but can't this be done with the javascript img tag?